# Classifying date as "yesterday", "last week", etc

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+------------+
| id | date_time  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 1464136759 | -- 5 days ago
| 2  | 1464436759 | -- 2 days ago
| 3  | 1464538248 | -- 6 hours ago
+----+------------+
--                     ^ these are based on current time which is 1464561158
```

Also I have this query:

```
SELECT id, CASE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time))
           WHEN CURDATE() THEN 'today' 
           WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 'yesterday'
           WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 'in last week'
           ELSE 'in last month or more'
           END range
FROM mytable
WHERE 1
```

And here is **current output:**

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     range     |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | in last month |
| 2  | in last month |
| 3  | yesterday     |
+----+---------------+
```

As you see my question selects all those unix-times wrong. Why and how can I fix it?

Here is **expected output:**

```
+----+--------------+
| id |    range     |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | in last week |
| 2  | yesterday    | 
| 3  | today        |
+----+--------------+
```

Comment: Your code works (such as it is) in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e63fd/3.  The code is not correct because of the third condition, but it does produce the expected output.

Comment: The timestamp is only relevant up-and-until the DATE, which is probably not very interesting. Remove it from the question for a clarified problem/scope.

Comment: @user2864740 I don't understand what do you mean ..

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the fiddle and yes it works on the fiddle. So why it doesn't work on the local? Should I set something like MySQL-timestap ?

Comment: If the values started as '2016-06-29 12:00:00' (or whatever), the most interesting part of the question would probably be reached. If the question *is* about timestamp *conversion* to an SQL DATE, then focus on that and remove anything about CASE. Make a clear question case eliminating unnecessary paths to reproduce the problem with the minimal example.

Comment: @user2864740 You know, all I'm trying to get is one of these: `today`, `yesterday`, `in last week`, `in last month or more`. Just that.

Comment: @user2864740 the OP in his code is removing the time portion from the date and only comparing dates. I thought the question was pretty clear

Comment: @JohnRuddell See the revision history :}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the logic that you want is like this:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesteray'
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
             ELSE 'in last month or more'
        END) as `range`
FROM mytable
WHERE 1;
```

Notes:

- There is no reason to extract the date.
- Clauses in a `case` statement are executed in sequence, so the first matching one will return a value.
- If your original code is failing, then this might fail as well.  Your original code should not have been returning only "yesterday".
- `range` is a reserved word, so it needs to be escaped.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e63fd/14) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, +1 ..! When I ask a database-question, I'm waiting for an answer from you .. please always do that :-) *(writing an answer for me)*

Comment: The yesterday Match was because his date(today)  was an exact match to curdate()-1  the case criteria for 'yesterday'. note that unix time is on UTC, in US for several hours curdate()-1 is our 'today' date

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you arent checking a range for the week on your third condition. Meaning...

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time)) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a33774/1)

Currently your code is saying `WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 'in last week'` if the date is equal to 7 days ago **ONLY**. the 25th is not the 22nd so it fails that check. You need to specify a range in order to get it to work.

Comment: Your fiddle works as well and thank you +1. Just the result of my local is different .. I really don't know why, Should I change something like MySQL-time? Because I think it isn't set correctly.

Comment: @Stack you can select CURDATE() to see what MySQL date you are getting. It could be your configuration is off.

Comment: also gordons fiddle doesn't work completely because it doesn't check for a range on the conditional :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell . . . My SQL Fiddle is a demonstration that the original code actually does work (after a fashion).  It is not intended to fix bugs in the original code, just to show that the results that the OP is getting are not reproducible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i know :) I was being tongue and cheek. Big fan of ur code :)

Comment: @Stack check your local mysql time and you can set it if you want. this link should help you if your time is off. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24904